# Error TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the error TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner, I'm not sure where i have went wrong. i'm new to this. I'm adding here my java.class file and log cat. can someone help me please?

```
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
List list = new ArrayList();

public ListDataAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

static class LayoutHandler{
    TextView NAME,PRICE,DESCRIPTION;
    Spinner CATEGORY;
}

@Override
public void add(@Nullable Object object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();

}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
        layoutHandler.NAME = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_flower_name);
        layoutHandler.PRICE = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_flower_price);
        layoutHandler.DESCRIPTION = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_flower_description);
        layoutHandler.CATEGORY = (Spinner)row.findViewById(R.id.text_flower_category);
        row.setTag(layoutHandler);

    }else
    {
        layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();


    }
    DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider)this.getItem(position);
    layoutHandler.NAME.setText(dataProvider.getName());
    layoutHandler.PRICE.setText(dataProvider.getPrice());
    layoutHandler.DESCRIPTION.setText(dataProvider.getDescription());
    layoutHandler.CATEGORY.setSelection(0);
    return row;
}
```

}

Here is my Log cat error.

> ```
> --------- beginning of crash
> ```
>
> 09-02 21:01:52.368 24696-24696/com.example.www.shop E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.www.shop, PID: 24696
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner
>           at com.example.www.shop.ListDataAdapter.getView(ListDataAdapter.java:59)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2378)
>           at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1977)
>           at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:711)
>           at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:772)
>           at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1723)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2170)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17707)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5588)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1858)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17707)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5588)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17707)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5588)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17707)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5588)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17707)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5588)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17707)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5588)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:727)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17707)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5588)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6353)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

Comment: Post your xml, but it's likely that `R.id.text_flower_category` is a `TextView`, not a `Spinner`

Comment: @TylerV Thank you. thats where i was wrong

Answer (score 1):

R.id.text_flower_category is a TextView, not a Spinner